# How to find the angular Invalid version 15.2-15.3 error?

Tags: angular-cli

I created a new angular app with the angular CLI 13.0.4. It created an angular app version ~13.0.0. When I use the command `ng build`, I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"

./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/noSourceMaps.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
```

These are the different version that I use:

[image]

What should I do to fix this error?

**------ UPDATE 3/2/2022 ------**

Contents of the **browserlist** file:

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# For the full list of supported browsers by the Angular framework, please see:
# https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
```

Comment: have a look at this -https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606 Post your browserlist file

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I commented out the line `last 2 Safari major versions` from the `.browserslistrc` file. The `npm build` is building the application successfully.

Comment: This worked, but i need safari support...

Comment: Fixed. But I would like to know why it is happening?

Comment: It looks like version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` , [regarding the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1062016148)

Comment: Updating the latest version of build-angular fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 30):

Try `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` since "error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"" this error is due to an invalid version installed, therefore as this was introduced in npm@6 audit fixing will automatically resolve dependence issues.

Comment: `npm audit fix --force` works

Comment: I got the error again, and the solution worked again

Comment: That's great if it worked for you as well

Comment: npm audit fix --force works!!

Comment: npm audit fix --force works for me. thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I had to run `npm audit fix --force` after updating `.browserslistrc`, and it worked for me.

[How to find the angular Invalid version 15.2-15.3 error](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606)

Answer (score 7):

Update this library to the latests major version and it should fix this issue

```
yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular -D
```

if you are using angular 13 e.g. run this command

```
yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.7 -D
```

or the same using npm

```
npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.7
```

Answer (score 5):

The command "npm audit fix" works for me

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I removed the last two Safari major versions from the `.browserslistrc` file after which the build is created successfully.

After removing the last two Safari major versions:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add

```
not ios_saf 15.2-15.3
not safari 15.2-15.3
```

in your `.browserslistrc` file of your project

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem after updating my browserslist, and `npm update` fixed it for me.

As explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1025189684) by an Angular collaborator:

> This is just a bug in the parsing logic of Safari browser versions

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution without changing `.browserslistrc` file(`npm audit fix` didn't work for me as well), update angular compiler to version 13.2.5+ as per [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1062016148)

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

run npm audit fix --force. it will be worked for angular 13 version